# Firebase Prevent Alphabetically Ordering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a structure that provides me adding likes to my profile's likes node. However i try to use this link to add post's key to my likes node but when i add old post to my likes node it does not add to the end. it adds automatically by alphabetic order. i don't want this. i want to add posts' key by like-date.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#data-model

```
{
  "data": {
    // This order doesn't matter, the order is taken from keys/(user1 or user2).
    "3": true,
    "1": "some data",
    "2": 5
  },
  "keys": {
    // These two users have different orders for their data thanks to key side ordering.
    "user1": {
      "1": true,
      "2": true,
      "3": true
    },
    "user2": {
      "3": true,
      "2": true,
      "1": true
    }
  }
}
```

First i like "3" and then i like "2" and "1" but it does not show like the structure above. it shows like this

```
"user2": {
          "1": true,
          "2": true,
          "3": true
```

but i want it to look like below.

```
"user2": {
          "3": true,
          "2": true,
          "1": true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys always appear ordered in the Firebase console.  There is nothing you can do to change the way the console displays data.

If you want to impose an ordering on your keys, you'll need to create some data under that key that you can use to order a query on that data.  For example, you may choose to put a timestamp under a node in order to create a chronological ordering.

Read more about [realtime database queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries) to find out what you can do.